# Help understanding Proof of the equality of the normal and the extended integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

[[image: enter image description here][1]]

This is a theorem from Spivak's calculus on manifolds.
How is the first inquality in the last line of the proof
established? [image]

Comment: Doesn't the step you've asked for only use $\int |f| \ge |\int f|$, which is usually proved by breaking $f$ into positive and negative parts?

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 this one  $M\int_A \Sigma_{\phi \in \Phi-F} \phi \leq M\int_{A-C} 1$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP should typeset it out and clarify their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spivak is summing up over all the partition of unity functions that are zero on $C$. Therefore, by the definition of a partition of unity, the sum is $1$ or less at every point of $A-C$ (less because conceivably some of the functions $\varphi$ that are nonzero on $C$ may be nonzero at points off $C$ as well).